# Add Elements of Custom Classes to A List

Tags: list, tuples

I have a custom class:

```
class Colorimetry
{
        
        public string DUT_Name;
        public double[,] SPD;
        public (int C, int g) Angular_Position;
        public int C;
        public int g;
        

}
```

containing a field as Tuple variable: `public (int C, int g) Angular_Position`

the I have a list of objects of this class:

```
List<Colorimetry> SPDs = new List<Colorimetry>();

SPDs.Add(new Colorimetry() { DUT_Name = "SPD1", CCT = 3000, Angular_Position.C=0 } );
SPDs.Add(new Colorimetry() { DUT_Name = "SPD2", CCT = 3020, Angular_Position.C=5 } );
```

I'm not allowed to declare a field in this way: `Angular_Position.C=0` - this is not valid

I can initialize all other field of this class but the filed defined as tuple. Why?